# Cookbook python not found

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I try to install python with chef solo.

To make it I do

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j chef.json
```

solo.rb:

```
file_cache_path "/tmp/chef-solo"
cookbook_path   "/home/lamerman/.berkshelf/cookbooks"
```

chef.json:

```
{
    "run_list": [ "recipe[python]" ]
}
```

ls -l /home/lamerman/.berkshelf/cookbooks

```
...
drwxrwxr-x 8 lamerman lamerman 4096 Sep 15 13:16 python-1.4.6
...
```

Why do I get

```
ERROR: Cookbook python not found. If you're loading python from another cookbook, 
make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

It seems like everything is right.

Comment: "If you're loading python from another cookbook, 
make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata", Did you do that?

Comment: @garnertb, I don't load python from another cookbook. I just try to install python with chef-solo. Where should I configure those dependencies? The python package was downloaded with Berkshelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkshelf and Chef itself use different directory structure than berkshelf. The main difference is that Berkshelf can have multiple versions of a cookbook installed while chef can not. In chef's world, the cookbook name must be the directory name, without any additions.

Thus, you can't just point the solo.rb to the berkshelf directory. Instead, you have to instruct Berkshelf to create a directory structure suitable for chef from its cache. This is akin to create a snapshot from the current state.

Thus, typically, you can run this in your chef repository (i.e. the directory that contains your `Berksfile`) to create a `cookbooks` directory suitable for chef:

```
berks install --path /path/to/your/chef/repo/cookbooks
```

Then, in your `solo.rb`, you can tell chef to use this snapshot directory

```
file_cache_path "/tmp/chef-solo"
cookbook_path   "/path/to/your/chef/repo/cookbooks"
```

Note that the names of the directories inside the `cookbooks` directory have no version appended. That is the way, chef requires it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One note: the install command seems to be deprecated,  "vendor" should be used instead